# What is deferwq

Tags: linux, kernel, archlinux

I'm a user of Archlinux and I'm trying to know what each and every process does. I found one that even Google can't tell me what it is. So what is the deferwq process for? Thanks!

Comment: SO is for programming questions, so this is off-topic. Probably best on [unix.se]